# enabling and disabling the script in unity

Tags: unity, c#

I have three gameobject(G1,G2,G3) and I have set their tag name as "enemy".And I have another gameobject(Manager) where I have attached the script and I have a button when I click on the button the script in all the three gameobjects should be disabled .But the problem is that ,the script is disabled for only one gamobject.

```
public void ArrowIndicatorInvisible()
{
    GameObject.FindWithTag ("enemy").GetComponent<MessageScript>().enabled=false;
}
```

What will be issue.Can anybod help me solving it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindWithTag` returns only the first `GameObject` with the tag. You need to use `FindGameObjectsWithTag` to retrieve a list of all `GameObject` that are in the Scene.

More info: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you probably need [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html), which returns an array of `GameObjects` rather than a single object

Once you have that you can loop over the objects like so:

```
public void ArrowIndicatorInvisible()
{
    GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy");

    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++) {
        MessageScript m = objs[i].GetComponent<MessageScript>();
        if (m != null) {
            m.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to  use `GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag()` store the result of this method in a array or list, then iterate over said collection and set the enable of the script for each one. Your current code returns only one active game object with the specified tag.